# Excel - returning a cell in a row only if multiple criteria from current row are matched

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet of transactions with unique IDs.

For each transaction, there may be two rows corresponding---one initiating, one fulfilling.

As new information keeps flowing in, I want to find the initiating rows if the current row is a fulfilling. Since they will have different IDs, the only way to match them is by the amount, type, account number, and transaction date.

Each of the criteria are not unique. For example, there may be many transactions with amount of $500.

As a result, I want to write a formula that returns the transaction ID if and only if all these criteria match a row in the spreadsheet.

I tried to work with arrays thinking i can multiply them since they will be either 0 or 1 and the product will only be 1 if all criteria match, but could not get it to work since it will just return one value, instead of an array of values.

So the spreadsheet has the following structure:

```
ID | Account Number | Transaction Date | Amount | Customer | Fulfilling order ID?    |
1 |     123456      |     06/26/2018   |   50   |   John   |                         |
2 |     123457      |     07/25/2018   |   55   |   Steve  |                         |
3 |     123456      |     06/26/2019   |   50   |   John   |         1               |
4 |     124588      |     07/25/2019   |   75   |   Rich   |                         |
5 |     125589      |     08/01/2019   |   80   |   Vincent|                         |
```

I want to be able to write something that will return 1, on order ID 3, since it is fulfilling order ID 1.

Comment: Please show us a sample set of data, and the formula you attempted.  What worked, and what didn't?  A [mcve] would be helpful (and what is being asked for).

Comment: So you tried something along the lines of `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1;(Range1=Criteria1)*(Range2=Criteria2)*(Range3=Criteria3);0))` entered as array through CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER??

Comment: @JvdV I tried, but I noticed that it's difficult to extend rows as new data come in, as it's not possible to "modify" part of the array, Further, in the formula I was not able to specify which "criteria" it is, since after I hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter, whatever I typed---the criteria for the current row---is used for the entire array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use dynamic ranges within array formulas, so you don't have to manually keep changing ranges when you enter data.

Something in cell `F2` along the lines of:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,($B$1:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))=B2)*($C$1:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C))=C2)*($D$1:INDEX(D:D,COUNTA(D:D))=D2)*($E$1:INDEX(E:E,COUNTA(E:E))=E2),0))
```

Entered as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, wouldnt work?

***Note*** 
*In your example it would never return a `1`, but just a `3` simply because the criteria don't match (column c, dates are different). As soon as they are the same, the formula works.*

[image]

Comment: Great catch! I will try the formula ASAP when I get a chance and let you know how it goes and accept answer.

Comment: What's the `1` in `MATCH(1`? Is it simply a placeholder?

Comment: It's the first parameter in the MATCH syntax representing the lookup value. It has to be 1, since we are looking for the first positive match of all arguments. Multiply all these argument through evaluate, you'll notice it will return an array of 0s and 1s. Our function will return the index of the first one within that array.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand the logic now. I will go home and look at it more as to why it's not yet working (I must have made some mistake here and there).

Comment: Make sure to make the first parts of all ranges absolute (between dollar signs) so they won't shift when you drag your formula down! Good luck

Comment: Hmm, I am getting 1s for every fulfilled column. I couldn't seem to figure out why. To me, the fact that all cells has "=B2" makes this array formula quite hard to debug (maybe there Excel can improve on this...)? I tried entering not as an array formula, and parsed each parts by highlighting and pressing F9, the formula works then, but returns #N/A if it's not manually parsed.

Comment: @user101998, replicate the sample data I used too, get the formula working there first, debug it and try to replicate what you did on the full dataset. + It is an array, simple as that ;)

Comment: Thanks. I tried replicating on the sample data, and I entered the exact formula you had in the post, highlighted the entire column, press ctrl + shift + enter, and I get a column of ones. I would post the screenshot, but at where I work I'm blocked from image hosting sites :(

Comment: Please share the exact formula you used in f2

Comment: `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,($B$1:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))=B2)*($C$1:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C))=C2)*($D$1:INDEX(D:D,COUNTA(D:D))=D2)*($E$1:INDEX(E:E,COUNTA(E:E))=E2),0))` I also tried putting two negative signs in front of the multiplications to see if turning the true/false into 1/0 does anything. Doesn't help.

Comment: That looks fine. Then you should send me a workbook of that sample data, either your sample data or the way you confirm the formula is of.

Comment: How would I send the data to you? Or alternatively, could you send me your workbook? The one in the screenshot?

Comment: That's long gone, there are multiple websites that let you upload and share a file through a link. If I have a look at yours it could also be a better way, since I hope to let you know what was wrong.

Comment: Sure, I'll reproduce the workbook and upload it to one of the sites and let you know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have the file uploaded here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/5a31kv8f96ofoos/Array+Formula+Demonstration.xlsx

Comment: @user101998, you have entered it as a matrix (formulas in all cells are exactly the same). Copy the formula in `F2`, clear all formulas, paste the formula back in `F2`, enter through ctrl+shift+enter, drag the formula down. The whole point is that you drag the formula down due to relative cells. Now you were constantly comparing the second row over and over. Check the difference once you actually dragged the formula down ;)

Comment: Problem solved. I thought whenever Ctrl + shift + enter is used, it is automatically a matrix formula where you need to highlight all cells in the range. Thanks for clarifying and helping!